# Mechanism of ring opening of amine combined with formylation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is the mechanism for this reaction? The tertiary amine is converted into an amide and the ring gains a double bond. I can't figure out how the C-O double bond would be formed.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's the easy part, but can you figure out what happens earlier? That's more interesting part.

Comment: Find the nucleophile. Find the electrophile. Combine.

Comment: Hint. The amide is a formyl amide. Where does the H attached to the carbonyl come from?

Comment: Can chloroform react with sodium hydroxide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: reaction mechanism]

This reaction is very similar to Reimer-Tiemann reaction which also consists of the reagent $CHCl_{3}$ + $NaOH$. The mechanism of that reaction is believed to have dichlorocarbene intermediate too. A good point to remember is that the dichlorocarbene intermediate is often used to form cyclopropane or carbonyl groups.

[image: reimer tiemann reaction]

This is the mechanism for the reimer tiemann reaction. We can see the similarity in the this reaction and the one you have mentioned previously.

Comment: Mm, that's better. Although the arrows still suggest an intramolecular proton transfer which I don't like...

Comment: @orthocresol I am not sure if I should discuss this here, but I will be honest, I am a 12th grade student and hence couldn't understand the terms you used earlier. I don't understand what correction there should be here. Can you please elaborate in simple terms, or can we discuss it in chat?

Comment: To deprotonate a X–H bond, the base (let's say B) needs to come from the *opposite* side of the hydrogen, i.e. X–H···B. That's essentially like an SN2 reaction, and the reason is the same: you need to get to the σ* orbital. This makes an intramolecular deprotonation essentially impossible, because that lone pair that is supposedly doing the deprotonation can't reach the σ* orbital. More likely that the negative charge picks up a proton from somewhere else, and the proton on the ring is lost some other way.

Comment: Apart from that nitpick, your mechanism is fine, though; your edit fixed the other things I pointed out. But I'd still ask you to type out your text, instead of attaching a *picture* of written text. It's easier for everybody else to read, and can be searched for.

Comment: I will grant that that the σ* orbital seems very difficult  align. I just thought that the aromaticity would drive it to be essentially SN1 type acid base reaction. I guess the arrows seem to direct people into thinking this is SN2( in which case should I just get rid of them and add equilibrium arrows?) I will update this answer to text format once my major exams get over (because I don't mainly know how to do TeX and draw custom images.) That being said thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Yes it’s the arrows that are the issue. Removing them is fine.